# deploying spring boot war generated file to tomcat server, TemplateResolver not locating files

Tags: spring, tomcat, thymeleaf

I am developing a Spring boot web application and everything runs fine when I run it like so

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n -jar build/libs/MobileQuestionnaire-0.1.0.jar
```

But if I try to deploy the war to Tomcat 8, it loads correctly but I think there is a problem with my "TemplateResolver" bean. Here is my MVC config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"controler","data.service"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "data.dao.repository" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "data.domain" })
@PropertySource("classpath:properties\\config.properties")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    private static String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { 
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", 
        "classpath:/static/", 
        "classpath:/public/" };

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "DataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("database.driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.driverManagerDataSource.setUrl"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.driverManagerDataSource.setUsername"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.driverManagerDataSource.setPassword"));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("data.domain", "data.dao.Repository");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    public Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }



    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setPageParameterName("page.page");
        resolver.setSizeParameterName("page.size");
        resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);    
        resolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("pagenation.pagesize")));
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }


    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

        messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setBasename("local/messages");

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean(name="localeResolver")
    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }


    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurerAdapter mvcViewConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
                registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/login");
            }
        };
    }



}
```

Here is my Thymeleaf Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        final TemplateResolver resolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

[image: Dir layout]

So I'm sure I don't understand fully the difference between running my jar file "MobileQuestionnaire-0.1.0.jar" and running my war file in Tomcat.

If you require more infomation please just ask and I'll provide.

Thanks very much.

EDIT:

Ok, so I've managed to set tomcat to let me attach a debugger and I've hooked Elcipse up to it and I've done some digging.

[How to set up debugger in tomcat](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/07/14/how-to-remotely-debug-application-running-on-tomcat-from-within-intellij-idea/)

It fails here:

```
templateInputStream = resourceResolver.getResourceAsStream(templateProcessingParameters, resourceName);
```

It tries to get the file

```
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(final TemplateProcessingParameters templateProcessingParameters, final String resourceName) {
        Validate.notNull(resourceName, "Resource name cannot be null");
        final File resourceFile = new File(resourceName);
        try {
            return new FileInputStream(resourceFile);
```

And it fails here. The path is:

```
\src\main\resources\templates\home.html
```

When I look in the web apps folder in Tomcat that file is in another location:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\MobileQuestionnaire\WEB-INF\classes\templates\home.html
```

So I think I need to update the template resolver so that it looks in the correct position. Any suggestions?

-Cheers

EDIT

Ok, so this issue is simply Tomcat not being able to locate my html/resources in the war file. This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.1.1'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.0.RELEASE'

    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'


jar {
    baseName = 'MobileQuestionnaire'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.+")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.0.3")
    compile("org.webjars:jquery:2.0.3-1")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
    compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}
```

And this is my web app directory structure (minus the lib folder) after I deploy it:

```
....\App>dir /b /s | sort
....\App\META-INF
....\App\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
....\App\META-INF\war-tracker
....\App\org
....\App\org\springframework
....\App\org\springframework\boot
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\Archive$Entry.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\Archive$EntryFilter.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\Archive$EntryRenameFilter.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\Archive.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\ExplodedArchive$FileNotFoundURLConnection.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\ExplodedArchive$FilteredURLStreamHandler.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\ExplodedArchive.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\FilteredArchive$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\FilteredArchive$2.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\FilteredArchive.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\JarFileArchive$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\archive\JarFileArchive.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data\ByteArrayRandomAccessData.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data\RandomAccessData$ResourceAccess.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data\RandomAccessData.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data\RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data\RandomAccessDataFile$FilePool.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\data\RandomAccessDataFile.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\ExecutableArchiveLauncher$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\InputArgumentsJavaAgentDetector$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\InputArgumentsJavaAgentDetector.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\Bytes.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\Handler.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarEntry.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarEntryData.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarEntryFilter.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarFile$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarFile$2.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarFile.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarURLConnection$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\JarURLConnection.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\jar\ZipInflaterInputStream.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\JarLauncher.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\JavaAgentDetector.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\LaunchedURLClassLoader$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\LaunchedURLClassLoader$2.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\LaunchedURLClassLoader$Java7LockProvider.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\LaunchedURLClassLoader$LockProvider.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\Launcher.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\MainMethodRunner.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\PropertiesLauncher$1.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\PropertiesLauncher.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\util
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\util\AsciiBytes.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\util\SystemPropertyUtils.class
....\App\org\springframework\boot\loader\WarLauncher.class
....\App\WEB-INF
....\App\WEB-INF\classes
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\Application.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\eunms
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\eunms\ENUM_ENABLED_STATUS.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\eunms\ENUM_HTML_RESOURSES.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\eunms\ENUM_LANGUAGE$1.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\eunms\ENUM_LANGUAGE.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\eunms\ENUM_USER_ROLES.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\MvcConfig$1.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\MvcConfig.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\ThymeleafConfiguration.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\converters
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\converters\ConverterCompany.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\converters\ConverterUsers.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\converters\ConverterUsersRoles.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\PageWrapper$PageItem.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\PageWrapper.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\RandomGenerator$1.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\RandomGenerator$Mode.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\RandomGenerator.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\util\RandomString.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\configuration\WebSecurityConfig.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\controler
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\controler\AdminController.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\controler\CompanyAdminController.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\controler\MainMenuController.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\controler\NotLoggedInController.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\dao
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\dao\repository
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\dao\repository\CompanyRepository.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\dao\repository\UsersRepository.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\dao\repository\UsersRolesRepository.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\Company.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\form
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\form\CreateCompanyForm.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\form\CreateUsersForm.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\form\CreateUsersRolesForm.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\form\EditCompanyForm.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\form\EditUsersForm.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\Users.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\domain\UsersRoles.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\service
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\service\CompanyManagment.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\service\CompanyManagmentImpl.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\service\SecurityService.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\data\service\SecurityServiceImpl.class
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\local
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\local\messages_en.properties
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\local\messages_es.properties
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\properties
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\properties\config.properties
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\css
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\css\menu_listing.css
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\css\style.css
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\images
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\images\icon_ADMIN.png
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\images\icon_ADMIN_createcompany.png
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\images\icon_ADMIN_viewcompany.png
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\images\icon_COMPANY_ADMIN.png
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\images\icon_mainMenu.png
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js\sample.js
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js\timeStampPicker
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js\timeStampPicker\cal.gif
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js\timeStampPicker\next.gif
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js\timeStampPicker\prev.gif
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\static\js\timeStampPicker\ts_picker.js
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\adminMenu.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\assignUserRoles.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\companyAdminMenu.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\createCompany.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\createUser.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\editCompany.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\editUser.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\error.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\home.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\login.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\mainMenu.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\viewCompanies.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\viewCompany.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\viewUser.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\viewUserRoles.html
....\App\WEB-INF\classes\templates\viewUsers.html

....\App>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Make sure CATALINA_HOME is set as a class variable because Tomcat uses that to figure out where the files are located. Once I set CATALINA_HOME to point to the bin directory in the Tomcat folder, everything worked

When running the jar file, use this bean:

```
/*
     * This is for when we run the jar file
     */
    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        final TemplateResolver resolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }
```

When we run on Tomcat, use this bean:

```
/*
     * This is for when we run it on the Tomcat server
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/src/main/resources/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;

    }
```

If both beans are present, the jar will work.
If both beans are present, the war will not work.
The war will only work with the second bean present.